# Delegation and dismissal of a view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm doing an app that has a UITableViewController populated with a list of products. Each row segues to a UIViewController that presents the details of the product in the row. Now since tapping on each row and going back to see the details of the next product might be too tedious for the user, we decide to add this feature: when a user swipes on the UIViewController of a product, then the UIViewController with the details for the next product is pushed.

But, as of now, I'm not sure of the best way to implement this. I'm tempted to pass the array of products to the UIViewController so that the swiping is achieved but this will be a violation of the MVC framework,right? Views cannot own the data they're presenting. The product details UIViewController should only know about the specific product that's passed to it, not the rest, right?

I think this can be accomplished using delegation but I'm not sure how. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

EDIT:
Rob Mayoff's code was really helpful so I decided to implement it. But for the meantime, instead of implementing a swipe, I'll just use a simple round rect button to call the functions.

```
- (IBAction)showNextProduct:(id)sender {
    [self.productsTVC goToProductAtIndex:self.productIndex + 1];
}

- (IBAction)showPriorProduct:(id)sender {
    [self.productsTVC goToProductAtIndex:self.productIndex - 1];
}
```

But every time I click any of the buttons, my app crashes with the message: `Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted. Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ProductDetailsViewController: 0x6e510c0>.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a `CatalogViewController` (which is a subclass of `UITableViewController`) and a `ProductViewController` (which is a subclass of `UIViewController`).

The simplest way to implement “swipe to next product” is to give the `ProductViewController` a reference to the `CatalogViewController`.  It should be `weak` (if using ARC) or `assign` (if not using ARC).  You will also want a property that holds the index of the product in the catalog:

```
@interface ProductViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) CatalogViewController *catalogViewController;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger productIndex;

@end
```

Then in the action method for a swipe, you send a message to the `CatalogViewController` asking it to go to the next (or prior) product in the catalog:

```
@implementation ProductViewController

- (IBAction)showNextProduct:(id)sender {
    [self.catalogViewController goToProductAtIndex:self.productIndex + 1];
}

- (IBAction)showPriorProduct:(id)sender {
    [self.catalogViewController goToProductAtIndex:self.productIndex - 1];
}
```

In `CatalogViewController`, whenever you create a `ProductViewController`, you need to set those properties:

```
@implementation CatalogViewController

- (ProductViewController *)productViewControllerForProductAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index < 0 || index >= self.products.count)
        return nil;
    ProductViewController *vc = [[ProductViewController alloc] initWithProduct:[self.products objectAtIndex:index]];
    vc.catalogViewController = self;
    vc.productIndex = index;
    return vc;
}
```

and you implement the `goToProductAtIndex:` method like this:

```
- (void)goToProductAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    ProductViewController *vc = [self productViewControllerForProductAtIndex:index];
    if (!vc)
        return;
    NSMutableArray *vcs = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
    while (vcs.lastObject != self)
        [vcs removeLastObject];
    [vcs addObject:vc];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcs animated:YES];
}
```

You can use the same method to handle a table row selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self goToProductAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

If you want to get more software-engineery, you can create a protocol around the `goToProductAtIndex:` method and use that to avoid making `ProductViewController` know about the `CatalogViewController` class.

Comment: thanks @rob. I'll try this solution and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: rob, I got an error message: "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."  and "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ProductViewController: 0x6d83740"

Comment: Make sure all of your `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, `viewWillDisappear:`, and `viewDidDisappear:` methods call their `super` methods.

Comment: I get other errors, I'll reload the code. btw rob, will putting the views inside a scrollView be easier? I think I'll achieve the similar swiping effect (like the iphone app of The Economist magazine).

Comment: I doubt it's easier.  If you have more than a few products, you may need to dynamically load the product views and add them to the scroll view, to avoid using too much memory.  You should watch the “Designing Apps with Scroll Views” video from WWDC 2010 and the “Advanced ScrollView Techniques” video from WWDC 2011.  [Apple Development Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/)

Comment: If you want to target iOS 5, you could use `UIPageViewController` to make it really sexy.  This is covered in the last 15 minutes of the “Implementing UIViewController Containment” video from WWDC 2011.

Comment: yeah my target is iOS5, great I'll check that out. thanks for pointing out the resources.

Comment: *[Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6)* has a section about object initialization that discusses how to implement initializers.

Comment: Ok thanks, rob, even if I call the super methods of the view lifecycle methods, my app still crashes every time I call the showNextProduct: or showPriorProduct:.... It has something to do with the setting of view controllers in - (void)goToProductAtIndex:(NSInteger)index?

Comment: the weird thing is, when I click the button, xcode doesn't stop at the breakpoint I set at     [self.catalogViewController goToProductAtIndex:self.productIndex + 1]; or ... -1

Comment: that's the thing, I also checked if the buttons are hooked up properly and they are. One thing I left out is that, when a row is clicked I have a segue set up. Does that have an effect?

Comment: rob btw, I was successful at implementing a UIPageViewController, thanks for the hint!